# rake aborted! no such file to load -- validatable (See full trace by running task with --trace)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I am installing a Ruby on Rails web application and am facing a problem when applying the `rake db:migrate` command.

`rake db:migrate` causes the mention error, the full trace is below:

```
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
D:/Ansi/ansi_smspro342/vendor/plugins/fedena_oauth2_provider/lib/oauth2/provider/model_base.rb:3
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
D:/Ansi/ansi_smspro342/vendor/plugins/fedena_oauth2_provider/lib/fedena_oauth2_provider.rb:6
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
D:/Ansi/ansi_smspro342/vendor/plugins/fedena_oauth2_provider/init.rb:5:in `evaluate_init_rb'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:158:in `evaluate_init_rb'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:154:in `evaluate_init_rb'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:48:in `load'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:38:in `load_plugins'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `load_plugins'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:369:in `load_plugins'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:165:in `process'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
D:/Ansi/ansi_smspro342/config/environment.rb:5
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gem `validatable` is over 6 years old, so I am afraid to ask, what Rails version this project has.

Anyway, install the gem `validatable` (or run `bundle install`, if you did not) and migration should pass.

Answer (score 0):

ok I resolved the problem by installing the gem validatable.